# How can I configure Microsoft SCOM to read SNMP traps?

Tags: snmp

I have a tool which sends SNMP traps on critical events. Can I configure SCOM to receive those traps?

Is there any mechanism in [SCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Operations_Manager) which receives SNMP traps from other tools, like the Trap Receiver tool does?